# Java method to assign object field values with Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I was wondering whether it would be possible to have something like the following in Java:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    // constructors, getters, setters

    public void setField(String aFieldName, Object aValue) {
        Field aField = getClass().getDeclaredField(aFieldName);
        // use: aField.set(...) with proper type handling
    }
 }
```

I am really stuck in the setField method and any idea would be very helpful.

Thanks!

EDIT: The reason for this is that I would like to have a method in another class like the following

```
public static MyClass setAll(List<String> fieldNames, List<Object> fieldValues) {
    MyClass anObject = new MyClass();
    // iterate fieldNames and fieldValues and set for each fieldName 
    // the corresponding field value
    return anObject;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure:

```
aField.set(this, aValue);
```

To do type checking first:

```
if (!aField.getType().isInstance(aValue))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

but since calling `set` with a value of the wrong type will generate an `IllegalArgumentException` anyway, that sort of check isn't very useful.

Comment: Yes I tried this but the thing is I would like to add some kind of type checking and appropriate casting in the method. Any ideas?

Comment: You can do type checking if you want (but if all you do with a failed check is to throw, then that's pointless, since the reflection mechanism will throw for you). No casting will be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Though I'm at a loss as to why you would want to do it like that (since you already have getters and setters), try this:

```
Field aField = getClass().getDeclaredField(aFieldName);
aField.set(this, aValue);
```

For more info, [see this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html).

Comment: Silly of me. I edited my question in order to explain why I want it.

Comment: OK, is the answer good enough then? If you want to, you also have more specialized versions of `set`, such as `setLong`, `setFloat`, `setBoolean` etc. See the Javadoc referenced.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest a `map` instead of `List<T>`.

```
 for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry:map.entrySet())
  {
    Field aField = anObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(entry.getKey());
    if(entry.getValue().getClass().equals(aField.getType()))
         aField.set(anObject,entry.getValue());
  }
return anObject;
```